# Vim extension (via Python)?

Tags: python, vim

is it possible to extend vim functionality via custom extension (preferably, written in Python)?

What I need ideally is custom command when in command mode. E.g.

ESC

:do_this

:do_that

Answer (score 20, accepted):

vim supports scripting in python (and in perl as well, I think).

You just have to make sure that the vim distribution you are using has been compiled with python support.

If you are using a Linux system, you can download the source and then compile it with

```
./configure --enable-pythoninterp 
make
sudo make install
```

Inside vim, you can type

```
:version
```

to list the available features; if it has python support, you should see a '+python' somewhere (a '-python' otherwise).

Then, to check the usage of the python module, you can type

```
:help python
```

P.S: if you're going to compile the vim sources, make sure to check the available configure options, you might need to specify --with-python-config-dir as well.

P.P.S: to create a "custom command in command mode" (if I understand correctly what you mean), you can create a function "MyFunction" in a vim script (using python or the vim scripting language) and then invoke it with

```
:Call MyFunction()
```

Check

```
:help user-functions
```

for details

Comment: Hey orsogufo,

I'm having trouble with this ... the "+python" doesn't show up even after compiling with the --enable-pythoninterp option. I set the python-config-dir to /usr/lib/python2.4/

I am using a standard Debian distro.

Any suggestions? I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: @shafik23: this is quite strange; are you sure the compilation was successful? did you receive any warning? The best suggestion I can give you is to read carefully the output of configure and make... and  of course, if you find something strange you can ask a question! Cheers

Comment: @shafik23 I had a problem with symptoms like yours until I also installed the package python-dev. I followed the basic run of the instructions http://www.blog.deepinit.com/?p=6 i.e. edit Makefile in src/ to include CONF_OPT_PYTHON=’–-enable-pythoninterp’ line then 'make config' in src/ then make && make install from top level directory.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is. There are several extensions on http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php

It can be done with python as well if the support for python is compiled in.

Article about it: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/extending-vim-with-python/

Google is our friend.

HTH

Answer (score 4):

Had a problems to compile Vim with Python.

> ...checking if compile and link flags for Python are sane... no: PYTHON DISABLED" in the ./configure output.

On Ubuntu 10.04 you have to install `python2.6-dev`. The flags for `./configure` are:

```
--enable-pythoninterp
--with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.6/config
```

Make sure you got a path to directory, which contains `config.c` file. Also no `/` at the end of the path! That caused me problems.